# Terraform: Get id associated to each subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a list of subnets (1 public and 2 private) and I want to get id associated to each subnet.

My code structure is :

```
-- Dev
  -- main.tf
  -- vars.tf
-- modules
  -- sn
    -- ressources.tf
    -- vars.tf
```

This is my **main.tf**

```
# Create Public Subnet
module "public-sn" {
  source            = "../modules/sn"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  sn_az             = [ "********-3a" ]
  sn_cidr           = [ "********.0/24" ]
  sn_tags           = [ "********-sn-a" ] 
  sn_id             = module.sn.snId
}

# Create Private Subnets
module "private-sn" {
  source            = "../modules/sn"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  sn_az             = [ "eu-west-3a", "eu-west-3b" ]
  sn_cidr           = [ "********.0/24", "********.0/24" ]
  sn_tags           = [ "********-sn-a", "********-sn-b" ] 
}
```

This is my **ressources.tf** in ../sn

```
resource "aws_subnet" "sn" {
  count                   = length(var.sn_cidr)
  vpc_id                  = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block              = var.sn_cidr[count.index]
  availability_zone       = var.sn_az  [count.index]
  tags                    = { Name = var.sn_tags[count.index] }
}
```

This is my **output.tf** in ../sn as of now is empty. Please, help to get subnets IDs under those conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the **list** of the subnet ids, your output in `../modules/sn/output.tf` should be:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = aws_subnet.sn[*].id
}
```

Comment: @bhamichi you asked a followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600226/terraform-invalid-index-error-with-multiple-subnets-ids with this answer pasted into the question. Since this answer satisfied your question, please accept and/or upvote.